# Is it possible to use expression evalutions ${} to call Xacro namespace macros to create lots of robots efficiently? Want to avoid hard-coding

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, xacro, include, namespace

The below code is incorrect. Is there a way to do this properly to potentially make a `macro` that creates lots of robots.

```
<xacro:property name="suffix" value="_1" />
<xacro:include filename="$(find pkg)/urdf/model.urdf.xacro" ns="${suffix}"/>
<xacro:${suffix}.model_macro_name />
```

Resources:

- Xacro Repo: https://github.com/ros/xacro/wiki#expression-evaluation-